# Can an air chuck be used as a quick release?

Tags: tires, air

I bought a tire inflator/air compressor with a digital readout for home use.  It's pretty slick--you dial in the pressure you want and hit a button and it stops when it reaches that pressure.

The hose has an annoying screw-on fitting like this:

[image: photograph of an air hose with a screw-on female Schrader adapter]

But I'd much prefer the "snap to lock" adapter of tire pumps from yesteryear or even the squeeze adapters that gas stations have.  I'm letting several pounds of pressure out as I attempt to unscrew the adapter each time.

I'm wondering: can I get an air chuck (specifically [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/274150954625)) and use it as a sort of "quick release"?  How does the chuck depress the plunger in the valve?

[image: Photograph of an air chuck]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work but you'd need to make sure the thread diameter on the new connector would fit inside the hose once the old connector was removed, otherwise your going to be needing thread reduction adapters etc to help make it fit properly.

On the new connector you just depress the thumb trigger before attaching it to valve, this opens the silver sliding/locking gate allowing the valve to enter the connector. Once the valve enters the connector you release the thumb trigger which locks the connector onto the valve. The little brass piece you can see just under the silver gate depresses the valve core opening the seal, which in turn allows the air to flow.